# How to schedule periodic snapshot of a volume in AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

I want to know how can i take automated periodic snapshot using AWS Management console.

I tried hard but couldn't find anything relevant...,I don't want to do it using script. I am working on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do it is via  script; however, depending upon your reason for doing the periodic update, you may want to consider another storage; for example, if you are really doing backups of code or data, there are much better ways to accomplish that.